# jProgressBar vs Runnable or Callable Threads?

Tags: java

How would it be possible to use a `JProgressBar` in conjunction with `Runnable` or `Callable` threads rather than `SwingWorker` class?

I would like to have a progress bar where I could pass in a running thread and be able to show its progress in percentage!

Comment: How would you know how far along a runnable is? The runnable itself must provide progress support, otherwise all you can get in your progress bar component is 0% or 100%. You could come up with a timing solution that uses previously recorded times to calculate an estimated progress...

Comment: You can do whatever you want. The key is that the updating of the JProgressBar must be done on the Event Dispatch Thread. The point of using a SwingWorker is that is does this for you. The long running code is run in a separate Thread and then the process() method is invoked when the progress bar needs updating. The process() method runs on the EDT. If you use your own Thread you you are responsible for using SwingUtilities.invokeLater() when you want to update the progress bar.

Answer (score 0):

There's a post dated from 2005 on javalobby written by Master Santhosh Kumar where he shows how to use a JProgressBar and a Runnable.

http://www.javalobby.org/java/forums/t53926.html